# Changing the default Mail Client using VBS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, email, vbscript

I would like to change the default mail client to `http://inotes/` from Outlook.

I know `http://inotes/` is not accessible by the public

I would like to run a .js file or a .vbs file and change the client amoung other things.

Ideally it would have little or no user interaction (I know in Windows 7, UAC may pop up allowing certain actions and its ok)

### My Code

```
<script>
function changeMailClient(){
 location.href="mailto:https://inotes/";
}
</script>
<body onload="changeMailClient();">
</body>
```

Comment: If this were possible I would seriously hope it would be reported as a tremendous security issue.

Comment: Thanks for the concern about security but we have appropiate measures in place for security.

Comment: You don't if you can change my default mail client.  It's my security I'm worried about, not yours.

Comment: This is obviously for an Enterprise. Not designed to distribute to other people.

Comment: @Pointy He seems to _not_ talk about a public website doing it, but doing it through scripting, locally on a Windows system. Seems totally valid to me.

Comment: My actual point is that it's not possible without some additional component (ActiveX control, etc).  No browser provides a facility to do this.

Comment: @Pointy I do not see why you need to run it inside a browser. Just create a local VBS file and double-click it (or use "cscript" e.g.).

Comment: @UweKeim then why is the sample code a `<script>` tag (presumably) in an HTML document?

Comment: Do you know how to change it using a VBS file? I found some web articles that discussed how to manage it using JavaScript inside an HTML file. I would rather avoid that route if possible.